# $U \subset \mathbb R^n$ is an open set, $f \in C^1(U, \mathbb R^m)$. If $E \subset U$ is a null set, then $f(E)$ is also a null set.

Tags: calculus, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove the following statement:

Suppose $U \subset \mathbb R^n$ is an open set, $f \in C^1(U, \mathbb R^m)$. If $E \subset U$ is a null set, then $f(E)$ is also a null set.

The professor gave a hint: "any open subset in $\mathbb R^n$ can be exhuasted from inside by a finite union of closed boxes."

This statement is of course false, as a finite union of closed sets is closed. Could the teacher have meant countable? That would help immensely to prove what I want to prove. It's obviously true for an uncountable union of closed boxes, but what about countable? Is this true? If so, why?

Comment: I think what your professor means is that you can take finitely many to _approximate_ the set, but it takes infinitely many to fully exhaust. It was poor wording, but the idea is fine.

Comment: I doubt he meant approximating anything. This is calculus and measure theory, not numerical analysis. If he meant approximating, this is the first time he did so in this course

Comment: You're approximating a set from within.. Approximation doesn't _only_ mean a Taylor series type approximation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is true for countable instead.
I spent *far* too long creating this diagram in Ti*k*Z some time ago, it may help:
[image]
[image]
Can you see how iterating this process gives the open set as a countable union of boxes? It additionally shows that each of the boxes can have rational (in fact dyadic) coordinates.

Comment: Could you add also the code of these beautiful pictures?

Comment: Holy crap. This is insane. I can't imagine how many hours it took to do this in Tikz. I've done basic ladder diagrams in Tikz and that was time-consuming enough! $+1$ just for the diagram.

Comment: The code is not remotely beautiful, the coordinates of each box were just done by eye :( It was just procrastinating doing actual work...

Comment: Oh my that's lovely.

Comment: So every open set is equal to a countable union of closed boxes that are all strictly inside it?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke https://gist.github.com/b-mehta/f1295f14035448ba9e2258e44f97eefa

Comment: @OriaGruber Yes, exactly!

Comment: Thank you for this beautiful illustration. It's not a proof for this incredible statement, but it's the next best thing.

Comment: @B.Mehta Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that he meant "Any open subset in $\Bbb{R}^n$ can be exhausted from inside by a sequence of sets, all of which are finite unions of closed boxes." The word "[exhausted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exhaustion_by_compact_sets)" in this context implies that one is considering a sequence of sets, not a single set.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the Lindelof property, there is a simple proof: For every $x\in U,$ there exists an open cube $C_x$ such that $x\in C_x\subset \overline {C_x} \subset U.$ By the Lindelof property, there exists a countable subcollection $\{C_{x_1}, C_{x_2}, \dots \} \subset \{C_x|x\in U\}$ such that

$$U=\bigcup_{x\in U}C_x = \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}C_{x_k}.$$

We then have

$$U=\bigcup_{x\in U}C_x \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\overline {C_{x_k}} \subset U.$$

The collection $\{\overline {C_{x_1}}, \overline {C_{x_2}}, \dots \}$ thus has the desired property.

Comment: May I ask why $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} \overline{C_{x_k}} \subset U$?

Comment: @OriaGruber In the second line I have $x\in C_x\subset \overline {C_x} \subset U.$