# Can a Measurable set be written as union of rectangles?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a Lebesgue measurable set. My question is: can $A$ be written as countable union of (closed) rectangles? i.e. $\exists \, Q_k \subset \mathbb{R}^n , k\in \mathbb{N}, $ (closed) rectangles such that \begin{align*}
A = \cup_{k=1}^{\infty} Q_k 
\end{align*}

Thanks!!

Comment: Obviously not. Union of closed rectangles are Borel, while there are non-Borel sets, still measurable.

Comment: No.  For example, you cannot write the line $y=x$ as a countable union of closed rectangles.

Comment: It is not true, but you may be interested in the related result that [open subsets can be written in this form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2743238/u-subset-mathbb-rn-is-an-open-set-f-in-c1u-mathbb-rm-if-e-subs/2743247#2743247)

Answer (score 2):

The set $\mathbb I$ of irrationals in $\mathbb R$ is an example. It's Lebesgue measurable, is uncountable, and has no interior. Thus no closed interval except for a singleton can lie in $\mathbb I,$ and there are uncountably many of these.