# Is it true that every open set in Euclid space is a countable union of open (closed) cubes?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

There is a theorem in the book but it only applies to $\mathbb{R}$ and open intervals. The proof seems to be unnecessarily complicated. Can I just say I can cut the space countably many times (bisecting the cubes each time) and each point is either in or not in the final collection?

Comment: Have a look at the answers given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2743238/u-subset-mathbb-rn-is-an-open-set-f-in-c1u-mathbb-rm-if-e-subs/2743247#comment5660248_2743247).

Comment: The proof that you saw is probably as simple as you said, it is just tedious to write in detail. As you said, divide the space in a grid of (hyper)cubes with side $1/2^n$. Take the union of all the (hyper)cubes completely inside the open set. Call that union $K_n$. Then take the union of all $K_n$ for $n=1,2,3,...$. Of course, to make this into a proof you need to show that all points of the open set get covered by this union and that no more points get covered.

Comment: This is much easier if you know the Lindelof property.

Comment: @zhw. Yes. That a separable metric space is second-countable and therefore hereditarily Lindelof.

Comment: So it is true then? The proof I saw involves construction of a maximal open interval at each point and density of rationals. It is conceptually less intuitive for me.